# Is there any event of PrimeNg p-calendar which executed on TIME change?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, calendar, primeng

I have used PrimeNg v5.2.7 for From Date and To Date in my project and also gave minDate validation in **To Date** but if I choose **From Date** 30th jan 2021 and only change time in **To Date** then today's date 27th jan 2021 is getting selected in **To Date** which is wrong senario

```
    <p-calendar class="date" [minDate]="null!=model.start_date?model.start_date:dateTime"
[(ngModel)]="model.end_date"
[showIcon]="true" [showTime]="true"                                                                           showButtonBar="true"                                             [formControl]="form.controls['end_date']"
(onSelect)="onChangeEndDate()" [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

You can **(ngModelChange)** in your calender. it will trigger when value of the field get changes.

```
<p-calendar class="date" [minDate]="null!=model.start_date?model.start_date:dateTime"
[(ngModel)]="model.end_date"
[showIcon]="true" [showTime]="true"                                                                           showButtonBar="true"                                             [formControl]="form.controls['end_date']"
(onSelect)="onChangeEndDate()" (ngModelChange)="onChangeEndDate()" [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
```

I think this will help you...

Comment: Thank you for this! but I have solved it by applying the same method on both the p-calendar and checked for the condition that if start_date > end_date and if yes then just do start_date = end_date.